# Match Email with Company's URL with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a very simple contact from but for the business requirement we need to validate the company's url with the contacting user's email

If your email is **user@examplecompany.com** and your url is **http://examplecompany.com**, the form will go through.

I'm trying to do it using regex, but I can't for the life of me, figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code so far:

```
    validateEmail = (email, url) => {
       let rootUrl = url.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/?\n]+)/)[1];
       let emailDomain = email.match(/@(.*)/)[1];
       return rootUrl === emailDomain;
    }
```

My emailDomain is returning `undefined`.

Comment: _"I'm trying to do it using regex"_ - Why? `window.location.host` + `String.prototype.split()` and you're almost done

Comment: The form is intended to be a lead generator. It's intended to be for third parties. So I can't use `window.location.host`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to implement it with regex as following.

```js
const validateEmail = (email, url) => {
  let regex = /(https?:\/\/)?(\w*\.)?(\w*\.\w*)/
  let rootUrl = url.match(regex)[3];
  let emailDomain = email.match(/@(.*)/)[1];
  return rootUrl === emailDomain;
}

// Testing
let emails = ["user@examplecompany.com", "user@othercompany.com"]

let urls = ["http://examplecompany.com", "https://examplecompany.com", "http://www.examplecompany.com", "https://www.examplecompany.com","examplecompany.com", "www.examplecompany.com"]

urls.forEach((url) => {
  emails.forEach((email) => {
    let valid = validateEmail(email, url)
    console.log(`email = ${email}, url = ${url}, isValid: ${valid}`)
  })
})
```

You could also try to use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) api (of course, it doesn't work on IE) to extract the hostname, and then extract domain name to compare with email address's domain name.

Comment: When I run your code snippet I get: `"message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group","filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 1,
  "colno": 23`

Comment: @Toto Thank you for pointing out. I realized that the Named Capturing Groups is ES2018 feature, some browsers like firefox haven't support it yet. Just edited it and use index based group capturing.